# Examples on using STM32Crypto Library along with other SSL/TLS libraries

Tags: stm32

I am working on a project with STM32H753 microcontroller which requires usage of SSL/TLS library functions along with Cryptographic functionalities. I see online and most of the examples I find are either using Mbed TLS or WolfSSL or similar completely.

I am looking for a case where I could use the [X-CUBE-CRYPTOLIB - STM32 Crypto Library](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-cryptolib.html) for all the cryptographic functionalities and use the SSL/TLS functionalities from Mbed TLS/WolfSSL, since the STM32 Cryptolib does not provide the same. Is that possible? Can anyone point to some examples or sample projects in this regard?